# MUI Rating component is rendering revert

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using MUI with react js. I have used this piece of code but it is not working properly. can anybody have a solution for this?

```
<Rating name="simple-controlled"/>
```

> [MUI Rating Component](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-rating/)

[image]

Comment: check if the name of the Rating input **simple-controlled** is used in another part of your code  . It must be a unique value on the entire page because MUI uses this name to generate IDs

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution in the theme file, I just change my direction 'ltr' to 'rtl'.

```
const themeOptions: ThemeOptions = useMemo(
   () => ({
      palette: palette.light,
      typography,
      breakpoints,
      shape: { borderRadius: 8 },
      direction: 'rtl', // before: 'ltr', after: 'rtl'
      shadows: shadows.light,
      customShadows: customShadows.light,
    }),
   []
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const theme = createTheme({
    direction: "rtl",
  });

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Rating name="simple-controlled" />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.